# How can we use getApplicationContext() without any implementation?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Here is one code I got on `sharedpreferences`. In this `getApplicationContext()` and `getSharedPreferences()` methods of Context class is used but both `getApplicationContext()` and `getSharedPreferences()` are abstract then how we can we use them without any implementation?

Edit 1:

I am saying that sharedpreferences object is created using above code but both the methods used are abstract then how can we use them without implementing them?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Clearly ask the queston?

Comment: try `PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`..you don't need to override those methods if you're doing this in `Activity` or `Service`

Answer (score 0):

It really depends where you are and what are you trying to accomplish. [Please read more about Android context](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/). Generally speaking you want to access the shared preferences because you want to store some values, and usually you are in an Activity class. From an Activity, you have two ways to access the context: *getBaseContext()* and *getApplicationContext()*. The former will provide you the base context, which is unique per instance, the latter will provide you the application context, which is unique per process. The system will create the base context's implementation(s) for each Activity when it gets created, and it will create the application context implementation when the process is created, for you. What you are seeing is their's abstract declarations, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext() and  getSharedPreferences() are abstract` - they are abstract in `Context` class, but implemented in it's children. For example, `Activty` is a child class of a `Context`, and it has implementation of `getApplicationContext()` like following:

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return mBase.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Where `mBase` is some non-public implementation of the `Context`, which is assigned to `Activity`, when it is attached to `ActivityThread`.

You can easily inspect **Android sources**, and find this, and more other interesting things on your own.